# Jquery XML working in Firefox not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, function, loops

```
var xml = 'XML text';

$('Collection > SubCollection', xml).each(function(){ 
alert("in);
}
```

This jquery function works fine in firefox, but not in IE, how can i get it to work in IE

Comment: make sure the case of the tags in your selector matches that of those in the XML, make sure `SubCollection` is only a **direct** descendant of `Collection`, and add another `"` in your alert, so it looks like this: `alert("in");`. Please post your XML.

Comment: Thank you for reiterating something you've already said. My comment asked you to provide _extra_ detail, so we might actually be able to help you, and also had some suggestions for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

I think any IE versions below 9 (maybe 9 too!) don't support this selector.
You will need to work around this just using class selectors for this to be cross-browser.

e.g.:
`$('.Collection .SubCollectionItem')`
This will give you all the items that have the 'SubCollectionItem' class and that are children of elements that have the 'Collection' class

Comment: It doesn't matter; the selector is parsed by jQuery which handles any cross browser issues.